# How to use AppendTo in do loop?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

```
list = {1, E, (3/2)*E^2 + (3/8), (5/2) E^3 + (25/8)};
AppendTo[list, 2*E*list[[{x - 1}]] + (2*x - 3) (2*x - 4) (2*x - 5) (1/4)*list[[{x - 2}]]]
```

Let x from 5 to 10, add terms to the list.
I have already try

```
list = {1, E, (3/2)*E^2 + (3/8), (5/2) E^3 + (25/8)};x = 5 ;AppendTo[list,2*E*list[[{x - 1}]] + (2*x - 3) (2*x - 4) (2*x - 5) (1/4)*list[[{x - 2}]]]
```

The result is correct.
But

```
Do[AppendTo[list, 2*E*list[[{x - 1}]] + (2*x - 3) (2*x - 4) (2*x - 5) (1/4)*list[[{x - 2}]]],{x,5,10}]
```

The result is NOT the same as the expectation.

How to edit to solve it?

Comment: Why do you use `list[[{x - 2}]]` instead of `list[[x - 2]]` ?

Comment: Generally, *don't* use `AppendTo` in a loop. Learn to use `Reap` and `Sow`.  Or where possible use `Nest`, `Table`, `Map` and things like that instead.

Comment: This looks like a job for `RecurrenceTable`.

Comment: Items 3 and 4 in `list` don't appear to follow the formula.  Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Nest`:

```
In[]:= res = Nest[
  Apply @ Function[{x, list},
    {
      x + 1,
      Append[
        list, 
        FullSimplify[
          2*E*list[[x - 1]] + (2*x - 3) (2*x - 4) (2*x - 5) (1/4)*list[[x - 2]]]
        ]
    }
  ]
,
  (* {x, initial list} *)
  {4, {1, E, (3/2)*E^2 + (3/8), (5/2) E^3 + (25/8)}}
,
  6 (* to go through 5 to 10 *)
]

Out[]= {
  10,
  {
    1,
    E,
    3/8 + (3 E^2)/2, 25/8 + (5 E^3)/2,
    (63 E)/4 + 3 E^3,
    5/16 (63 + 4 E (5 + 63 E + 4 E^3)),
    3/4 (525 + 42 E^2 + 420 E^3 + 8 E^4),
    5/2 E (1575 + E (5 + 4 E (90 + E^2))),
    3/16 (45045 + 4 E (4625 + E (45045 + 4 E (21 + E (925 + 4 E))))),
    5/8 (429975 + 2 E^2 (23499 + 2 E (86005 + 2358 E + 8 E^3)))
  }
}
```

And to get the result (without the step), just `res[[-1]]`.